# Gravatars on Main and Meta don't match

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-user, gravatar

The gravatars of this user's [main](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/68709/thomas)  and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/68709/thomas) account don't match?

How can that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They visited the 2 sites from different machines, and for users without an email - the hash is based on location.